# How to load image to collectionview from url obtained from json

Tags: iphone, ios, json, core-data, restkit-0.20

I have an IOS app that is using RestKit to pull json formatted data from a server into a CoreData Entity.  One of the attributes in the data is a URL for the image associated with the particular article.  I'm trying to load that image to my collectionViewController.  This is what I've been trying with no success.

From within

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

I am trying this

```
    NSManagedObject *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSURL *photoURL = [object valueForKey:@"imageUrl"];
    NSData *photoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:photoURL];
    cell.cellimg = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:photoData];
    [cell.title setText:[object valueForKey:@"title"]];
```

If I comment out the attempt to grab and load the image the view loads great with a default image and the titles of the articles received from the json data.  Based on that I know everything is coming in correctly.

I have also determined that `*photoData` is being assigned the correct URL. But each time I encounter the `NSData` line the console prints out "**-[__NSCFString isFileURL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance....**"

I honestly don't know if this is even the correct way to do this or if it will even work.  I  am pretty new at this so any help would be great.  Given that I am new some small code examples would really help as well as explaining the proper way to approach this.

Just in case here is the header file where I define `*cellimg` and `*title`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface GlobismNewsCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImage *cellimg;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *title;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSURL *imageUrl;

@end
```

Comment: Dharmbir you nailed it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using `NSString` as `NSURL`. So try to use this one...

```
NSURL *photoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:(NSString *) [object valueForKey:@"imageUrl"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Dharmbir I had this issue wrapped up within 25 minutes of asking the question!

To clarify for any new guys like me I changed the line Dharmbir suggested so the block looks like this now

```
NSManagedObject *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSURL *photoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:(NSString *) [object valueForKey:@"imageUrl"]];
NSData *photoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:photoURL];
[cell.cellimg setImage:[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:photoData]];        
[cell.title setText:[object valueForKey:@"title"]];
```

Notice the 4th line in the block also changed from this

```
cell.cellimg = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:photoData];
```

to this

```
[cell.cellimg setImage:[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:photoData]];
```

I also had to change my `*cellimg` property to this

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *cellimg;
```

from this

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImage *cellimg;
```

I had to change to the UIImageView class because the cell in my storyboard is based on the UIImageView Class.  Hope this helps a guy in need thanks again Dharmbir!